# TLB, CPUID and Hugepages?

Tags: c, linux, huge-pages

If I mount 64MB of 2MB hugepages to /mnt/huge2mb, which TLB entries are those pages using?  I `mmap()`-ed them in my C program.

`cpuid`'s output:

```
   cache and TLB information (2):
      0x63: data TLB: 1G pages, 4-way, 4 entries
      0x03: data TLB: 4K pages, 4-way, 64 entries
      0x76: instruction TLB: 2M/4M pages, fully, 8 entries
      0xff: cache data is in CPUID 4
      0xb6: instruction TLB: 4K, 8-way, 128 entries
      0xf0: 64 byte prefetching
      0xc3: L2 TLB: 4K/2M pages, 6-way, 1536 entries
```

I believe those mounted 2MB hugepages belong to data, and so they use data TLB entries.

However, the data TLB entries are for 1G and 4K pages.

Then, what TLB entries are used for those 2MB hugepages?  L2 TLB entries?  If yes, what is L2 TLB?  Is it for both data and instruction?  If yes, then there are overlapping for 4K pages for data -- data TLB and L2 TLB.  What's the purpose of the extra 64 entries for 4K pages then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I wouldn't necessarily assume that the data from CPUID itself is correct (over the years there's been various pieces of errata), and if the data from CPUID is correct I wouldn't necessarily assume that the code in Linux correctly interprets it  (over the years determining cache characteristics has become a horrible mess).

Without having any clue what the CPU is (and without being able to check if the information was correctly reported by CPUID and Linux); based on the information shown I'd be tempted to suspect that `0xc3: L2 TLB: 4K/2M pages, 6-way, 1536 entries` is used for instructions and data and will be used for your 2 MiB pages, but when these 2 MiB pages are used the CPU will also split the 2 MiB TLB entries into pieces and use `0x03: data TLB: 4K pages, 4-way, 64 entries` for (4 KiB pieces of) the 2 MiB pages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Since CPUID's output might not be reliable (as CPUID offers others to submit bugs for incorrect outputs), where can I find the reliable information about Intel Xeon Skylake CPUs?  I don't see it on Intel.com.

Comment: You mentioned `CPU will also split the 2 MiB TLB entries into pieces and use 0x03: data TLB: 4K pages, 4-way, 64 entries for (4 KiB pieces of) the 2 MiB pages.`.  Is there any document about it?  As I am curious why CPU would do so if L2 TLB already has the entries.  If the 4K-page data TLB is like the fallback for L2 TLB.  Then, how does it translate/lookup the virtual memory address pointing to somewhere in the middle of a 2MiB page?

Comment: For information about Skylake, maybe this site can help: https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/skylake_(server)#Memory_Hierarchy . Ironically (luckily?) this page mentions "Note: STLB is incorrectly reported as "6-way" by CPUID leaf 2 (EAX=02H). Skylake erratum SKL148 recommends software to simply ignore that value", so the `0xc3: L2 TLB: 4K/2M pages, 6-way, 1536 entries` output from Linux probably failed to account for that CPUID bug (and should say `0xc3: L2 TLB: 4K/2M pages, 12-way, 1536 entries`).

Comment: I'm not sure if there is/isn't any documentation for "2 MiB TLB splitting" - it's a "non-architectural implementation detail" (in other words, it's supposed to be transparent to software so there's no real need to document it). In general L2 means 'bigger but slower", so you'd want to bring it into L1 (smaller bug faster) for performance reasons (and if L1 data TLB only supports 4 KiB, then that can't work without splitting).

Comment: If my guess is right; for TLB lookup the CPU would check the L1 data TLB (`0x03: data TLB: 4K pages, 4-way, 64 entries`) and if it's not there it'd check the L2 TLB (`0xc3: L2 TLB: 4K/2M pages, 12-way, 1536 entries`). If it's not there either, then CPU would go down the "TLB miss" path (fetch TLBs from memory) and bring it into the L2 TLB and then the L1 TLB. If it was in the L2 TLB (but not in L1 TLB) then it'd just transfer the details from L2 TLB to L1 TLB (including calculating the address using "start of 2 MiB page" and "offset within 2 MiB for the 4 KiB we actually wanted")

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It is very helpful.  And confirmed that you are right -- CPUID's output is indeed wrong for Skylake -- it doesn't even mention L1 Data TLB for 2MiB/4MiB (really supporting 4MiB? new to me).  And it seems splitting might not exist in Skylake as it has L1 Data TLB for 2MiB pages already?

Comment: Ah - you're right - there actually is an L1 data TLB for 2 MiB/4 MiB pages (I didn't notice that earlier), and there wouldn't be any need for splitting. Not sure if that's something the CPU's CPUID forgot to mention or if it's a "quirk" in Linux's code, but either way it makes a lot more sense now. :-)